# how can I "pipe" all of these to xclip preservering newlines

Tags: shell, command-line, xclip

So, I'm creating this little convenience command for system information when bug reporting.

```bsh
alias clip="xclip -selection clipboard -in"
alias bug="echo $(lsb_release -irs && uname -r && free --human --giga) | clip"
```

The problem is/was two-fold, when I didn't do the `echo $()` it wasn't capturing the stdout of all commands, just the last one. Doing it this way, however, strips the newlines making it far less readable.

also, I notice that the `$()` is doing this when I actual run the alias `bug` but it doesn't when I run the command without the alias directly.

```
❯ bug                                                                                                                           # IdeaProjects
Fedora 33
zsh: 5.11.7-200.fc33.x86_64: command not found...
zsh: 10:20:16: command not found...
zsh: total: command not found...
zsh: Mem:: command not found...
zsh: Swap:: command not found...
```

whereas just running it on an interactive shell

```bsh
❯ echo $(lsb_release -irs && uname -r && uptime && free --human --giga) | clip                                                  # IdeaProjects

❯ Fedora 33 5.11.7-200.fc33.x86_64 10:39:11 up 3 days, 20:44, 1 user, load average: 0.70, 1.02, 0.97 total used free shared buff/cache available Mem: 15G 5.9G 2.3G 1.8G 7.6G 7.8G Swap: 12G 72M 11G
```

I don't understand why it would be different.

How can I write this as a single alias/command (I suppose a function is acceptable, in which case `zsh`) and retain the newlines?

p.s. if you have any suggestions on how to improve this for reports, feel free to comment that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subshell:

```
alias bug="(lsb_release -irs && uname -r && free --human --giga) | clip"
```

This will send all three commands’ standard output to `clip`, without processing whitespace.

Both aliases can be combined:

```
alias bug="(lsb_release -irs && uname -r && free --human --giga) | xclip -selection clipboard -in"
```

I wouldn’t format the `free` output too early; rounding can cause confusion:

```
alias bug="(lsb_release -irs && uname -r && free) | xclip -selection clipboard -in"
```

The problem you’re seeing with the `bug` alias comes from the fact that the command substitution is evaluated when the alias is defined; run `alias` to see what I mean:

```
$ alias
...
bug=$'echo Fedora 33\n5.11.7-200.fc33.x86_64\n              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available\n ...
```

So the alias becomes an alias for

```
echo Fedora 33
5.11.7-200.fc33.x86_64
total used free shared buff/cache available
...
```

which explains why you get the output you quote. When run directly rather than through an alias, the command works because it’s not evaluated a second time: the expansion of `$(lsb_release ...)` is given as arguments to `echo`, which outputs it as is (after whitespace processing by the shell).

[The quotes are significant](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution):

> If the substitution is not enclosed in double quotes, the output is broken into words using the `IFS` parameter.

So `alias bug="echo $(lsb_release ...)"` preserves the newlines, resulting in multiple commands when the alias is run, whereas `echo $(lsb_release ...)` doesn’t (and in any case, it wouldn’t matter because the command wouldn’t be re-interpreted).